# SSRS - Pie Chart - Multiple CollectedThreshold Properties

Tags: reporting-services, pie-chart, custom-attributes

Hopefully this is simple. I know how to choose a value in the property section for a collected threshold to group all values under a certain percentage; however, I want to know if it's possible to set 2 values. If so, how do I go about doing that?

For instance, group all values with a value of 1-3% into a pie slice and group all values with a value of 3%-10% into another pie slice with the rest of the values each getting their own pie slice.

[image: Image of the Properties Section in Question]

Comment: I don't believe that is possible unfortunately.

Comment: While I don't think this is possible using the pie chart directly, you could always add a calculated field to the dataset that calculates category based on value.  If the pie chart is keyed to groups instead of details, there's probably still ways to handle it, though it might be a little messy.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe a different graph for a larger dataset would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a caveat, while the answer below isn't hard to set up it is a bit ugly and not great for maintainability or efficiency.  I'd consider working on the query end to break out the categories.

You can set up the chart as a subreport and pass it the total as a hidden parameter (as you can't directly use aggregate functions in calculated fields or grouping expressions).  Then use a category grouping expression similar to the following, changing field names as appropriate:

```
=IIF(Fields!Value.Value/Parameters!Total.Value<0.03,"Other (<3%)",IIF(Fields!Value.Value/Parameters!Total.Value<0.10,"Other (<10%)",Fields!Name.Value))
```

If your dataset doesn't rely on any parameters, you could also skip the subreport and just set up an extra dataset that grabs the sum total and have an internal parameter default to that value.